# How to get a list of all values from instance variables in a python class

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class HTTP_HEADERS:
    ACCEPT = "X-Accept"
    DECLINE = "X-Decline"
```

To get all the variable names out of the class I can do something along the lines of:

```
members = [
        attr for attr in dir(HTTP_HEADER)
        if not callable(getattr(HTTP_HEADER, attr))
        and not attr.startswith("__")
    ]
```

This will return a list of variable names, like so:

```
["ACCEPT", "DECLINE"]
```

Now what I want to do, is get the values of those variables into a list. For example the output should be:

```
["X-Accept", "X-Decline"]
```

How can I do this successfully?

Comment: It looks like you should be using `enum`

Comment: Note, you aren't working with instance variables here ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this:

```
class HTTP_HEADER:
    ACCEPT = "X-Accept"
    DECLINE = "X-Decline"

names = ["ACCEPT", "DECLINE"]
```

Getting the values is simply a matter of

```
values = [getattr(HTTP_HEADER, name) for name in names]
```

I think a dictionary is more appropriate though, and it can be done with minimal change to your original code:

```
members = {
        k: v for k, v in vars(HTTP_HEADER).items()
        if not callable(v)
        and not k.startswith("__")
    }
```

which gives

```
{'ACCEPT': 'X-Accept', 'DECLINE': 'X-Decline'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define this as an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

```
class HTTP_HEADERS(enum.Enum):
    ACCEPT = "X-Accept"
    DECLINE = "X-Decline"
```

Now you can simply do:

```
[x.value for x in HTTP_HEADERS]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getattr` again to access class variable

```
[getattr(HTTP_HEADERS,m) for m in members]
```

Output

```
['X-Accept', 'X-Decline']
```